# Setting a column based on conditions when INSERTING data in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Currently working on a basketball performance database. The issue I'm having is storing the winner of a match. 
Match table is currently like so:

```
CREATE TABLE Matches(
M_ID int CONSTRAINT pk_Match PRIMARY KEY,
M_Date Date NOT NULL,
M_Location varchar(20),
M_HomeTeam int NOT NULL,
M_AwayTeam int NOT NULL,
M_HomeScore int NOT NULL,
M_AwayScore int NOT NULL,
M_Winner int,
CONSTRAINT fk_TeamHome foreign key (M_HomeTeam) REFERENCES Team(T_ID),
CONSTRAINT   fk_TeamAway foreign key (M_AwayTeam) REFERENCES Team(T_ID)
)
```

What I want is the value of M_Winner to be set to M_HomeTeam & M_AwayTeam foreign keys based on their scores.
I've been able to do this with this update statement

```
UPDATE Matches
SET M_Winner = CASE
WHEN M_HomeScore > M_AwayScore
THEN M_HomeTeam
WHEN M_AwayScore > M_HomeScore
THEN M_AwayTeam
END;
```

However I need it to work when the data is inserted.
Any ideas?

Comment: As @GordonLinoff will tell you in 30 seconds, you can use a trigger to do this.

Comment: Wrong :-) He has an even better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle 11g+, you can use a virtual computed column:

```
ALTER TABLE matches
    ADD m_winner as (CASE WHEN M_HomeScore > M_AwayScore
                          THEN M_HomeTeam
                          WHEN M_AwayScore > M_HomeScore
                          THEN M_AwayTeam
                     END)
```

Comment: Nice, didn't know that!

Answer (score 1):

You can define a trigger for that:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_ins_match
BEFORE INSERT ON Matches
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF :new.M_HomeScore > :new.M_AwayScore THEN
       :new.M_Winner = :new.M_HomeTeam
   ELSE
       :new.M_Winner = :new.M_AwayTeam
   END IF;
END;
```

Read about triggers in the [Oracle Developer's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_triggers.htm)